# Cycles render view is completely grey

Tags: cycles-render-engine, visibility

So i have a scene where i have 2 objects with a simple Principled BSDF shaders and it's lit with an HDRI. I tried to look at it in the render view, but for some reason it is entirely gray.

Here's how the viewport looks:
[image]

And here is how a render of the scene looks:
[image]

However, i have no problems in eevee, as you can see here:
[image]

Eevee render:
[image]

I have no idea what could be causing this. I also have some other objects in another collection, but the collection is disabled for render, so it probably isn't the problem.

Comment: Hello Daniela :). Your Render preview is *paused*. Just click the *play* symbol in top right corner.